# Use existing SQLite db in phonegap

Tags: database, sqlite, cordova

I'm trying to create some kind of dictionary app in phonegap where I have 200 words and their respective definitions. I want store this data in the app, and I'm trying with SQLite, but I've been searching and reading a lot of articles and what I've found is that I can't use an existing (and pre-populated) SQLite database, that I have to create the database in my app code. Is it true? 
I have no experience in phonegap, but it does not make sense to me not be able to use an existing db file.
What method can I use for keep this data in my app and use it?

Comment: if you cannot ship prefilled database, just ship a text file and load the db on first start, it will take a tiny amount of time to store 200 words

Answer (score 0):

You can either ship with a pre-populated SQLite with your application, or download a pre-populated SQLite database from a server when your application starts up, or create the database client side in your application's code.

When using a pre-populated database that ships with your app, you will need to copy that database to the app's data directory on first startup, so that you can connect to it and read data from it.

[This blog post](http://moduscreate.com/hybrid-mobile-apps-with-sqlite/) provides some detail on your options here.